# Spyder 4.1.4 seemingly "squished" some lines together with a jumbled line number and an irrelevant error

Tags: python, anaconda, spyder

Firstly, my apologies for the terrible title. I have no idea how to better describe this.

My configuration:

- **OS:** Ubuntu 20.10
- **IDE:** Spyder 4.1.4
- **Environment:** Anaconda 2020.07
- **Computer:** Lenovo Thinkpad X260

I'm writing some code to read and analyze a subset of monochromatic .tiff images (chosen via the value of a number in the file name) from a single folder. I am also fairly new to Spyder, and tried to tinker with the options for a bit; I noticed the issue only after I switched "Rendering engine" in Advanced Settings to "Automatic" from "Software" and then restarted Spyder. I do not know what this does but I thought it might aid with performance. I am unsure as to whether or not it might have caused the issue.

### The problem itself

My code appears to have jumbled multiple, empty save for 1, lines into a single line. Up to line 46, the line numbers are fine, but then there is a line where the line number is jumbled/garbled, and thereafter the line count skips to 51. When the problematic line is highlighted, it displays 50 as the line number.

[The jumbled line number.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JEYCH.png) | | [The problematic line, highlighted.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qWvv8.png)

The line itself also throws an irrelevant, seemingly misplaced error:

```
*runfile('/home/USER/Documents/AST325/Lab 2/lab2.py', wdir='/home/USER/Documents/AST325/Lab 2')
  File "/home/USER/Documents/AST325/Lab 2/lab2.py", line 47
    ￼
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid character in identifier
```

(I've substituted `USER` for my actual username.)

The .tiff files do have a hyphen in their name (which I plan to fix in short order), but they have not been called anywhere in the program at this point and I have ensured that every instance of a hyphen is inside a string (explicitly, or via `str()` ) so I do not know the reason why this occurs.

### Code and questions

Here is all of the relevant code:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
    # from viewImage.py
import os

#%% Dataset Import
def ImportDataset():
    """
    Our datastreams are recorded in 9 different datasets: xrayN-000...
    for N = 1 through 6, and noxrayN-000... for N=1,4,6. Ellipses are
    numbers, 00-50.
    """
    print("Import which dataset?")
    number = input()
    print ("xray set? (y/n)")
    print("('n' returns a dataset without xray exposure.)")
    print("Xray-less datasets are available for sets 1, 4 and 6.")
    # self explanatory
    yes_xray = input()
    if yes_xray == "y":
        fname = "xray" + str(number) + "-000"
    elif yes_xray == "n":
        fname = "noxray" + str(number) + "-000"
    else:
        print ("Incorrect input.")
        ImportDataset()
    return str(fname)

fname = ImportDataset() # We call this to set part of the filename.

#%% Displaying A Single TIFF Image

￼
￼
￼
print("Pick a number 00-50. Write a 0 for a number between 0 and 10.")
```

The last line is the problematic line. Notably, copying and pasting the code directly here does display the empty lines (47-49) absent from the Spyder GUI itself. Line 46, between the problematic `print(...)` line and the cell header ( `#%%` line) is empty in Spyder as well.

(EDIT: Copying the full code block and pasting it into a new .py file replicates the bug.)

I wanted to, at the least, document this phenomenon since I was unable to find any other reference to it. [Click here to see a cropped screenshot of my view in Spyder.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Kj86.png) I have not extensive tinkering since I wanted to accurately document the conditions under which the bug occurred at first.

Here are my main questions:

**1. Is it known what I could do I fix this and restore normal behavior to Spyder? Reverting the rendering engine to "Software" and restarting Spyder did not work.**

**2. What does the "software rendering" option (in Tools -> Preferences -> General -> Advanced Settings) do, roughly speaking, and can I expect performance gains from its options?**

**3. Is the reason for the `invalid character in identifier` error evident anywhere in my code?**

Thank you for taking the time to read, and please don't hesitate to recommend a better title or ask for clarifications. I'm quite new to coding and hope this was a sufficiently comprehensive post.

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) Please revert to software rendering to fix the problems you found. That option allows Spyder to use your graphics card to help rendering its interface, but it's set to Software by default to avoid issues with buggy graphics card drivers (which seems to be your case). I can't help you with your other issues, sorry.

Comment: @CarlosCordoba Thank you! For your information, the issue persisted even after reverting to software rendering. However, I was able to easily relocate the code on the non-bugged lines, so it did not cost me anything, fortunately.